# How can i get the real time data from Epic FHIR Resource?

Tags: hl7-fhir, smart-on-fhir

I'm using Open.epic to fetch data from fhir resources.
But my requirement is that after getting the patient data from the resource .
If there is any changes or updation on patient record (for eg : for lab test or medication) then it should be automatically update in my database without explicity calling it from the frontend

I read the documentation of openepic (https://fhir.epic.com/Sandbox) didn't find any solution there. there are CDS Hooks (https://fhir.epic.com/Documentation?docId=cds-hooks) but i don't think it is related to pulling real time data

for that do FHIR have any hooks, apis or any other trigger points from where we can get the data at realtime whenever they get added for the patients(or for specific encounter)

Answer (score 1):

Epic does not offer webhooks. If you need to be notified of changes, if there is an HL7v2 interface and trigger that would apply to the data you care about, you could receive notifications that way.

Comment: what do you mean by "HL7v2 interface", I tried it with Mirth Connect when discussing it with Epic support they said we should not use any third-party interface with fhir for getting real-time data.

Comment: HL7v2 is another data exchange technology, independent of FHIR (though both HL7v2 and FHIR were created by the same standards body).  See https://open.epic.com/Interface/HL7v2

Answer (score -1):

It seems like CDS hook is the only way to get notification from EPIC. There is a CDS hook for when the patient chart is opened. You can then use the patient ID to get other fhir resources like Encounter, etc. I haven't tried this but interested to know if anyone have